# how do I install edge rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how do I install the latest, unreleased version of rails?  i.e. edge rails?  have followed some suggestions but still seem to have version 2.3.5...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is run `rake rails:freeze:edge` in your project.

Another option if you haven't started your project yet is this:

```
mkdir -p foo/vendor
cd foo
git clone git://github.com/rails/rails.git vendor/rails
ruby vendor/rails/railties/bin/rails .
```

or, if you're planning to use git for your project:

```
mkdir -p foo/vendor
cd foo
git init
git submodule add git://github.com/rails/rails.git vendor/rails
git commit -m "Added Rails Edge as submodule"
ruby vendor/rails/railties/bin/rails .
```

Comment: thanks - the second instruction is the one I was looking for as I want to create my app using the edge.  thanks again.

Comment: you're welcome. btw, be aware that you might have to update/install some gems too.

Comment: yes thanks.  btw, for anyone who is interested, I've just been introduced to this - http://ci.rubyonrails.org/ - good source for info on the stability of the master branch