# How to properly pull in git patches for Rails, etc. while not part of the main project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github

I've run into an issue that was just recently patched in a rails branch a few days ago.  Specifically I need [this patch](https://github.com/dyba/rails/commit/30048b718194ee0765e960c91b2fb345ff75ab0e)

Now that's a pretty simple patch that could just be manually applied, however I'd like to better understand the git and github way of tackling this.

How would one go about pulling this in for utilization?  It seems from some comments that perhaps this has been integrated upstream now to Rails proper, however I am not sure nor is it clear how to figure this out.

Notwithstanding, I need this patch.  Perhaps it would be wise to run a local Rails repo and pull this into projects?  Or is there a preferred way?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043089/how-to-use-a-branch-in-a-fork-of-rails-in-a-project-with-bundler) which is dated back to Rails 2.x and it appears to have an interesting suggestion of pointing to a local repo:

```
gem 'rails',            :path => 'rails/railties'
gem 'actionmailer',     :path => 'rails/actionmailer'
gem 'actionpack',       :path => 'rails/actionpack'
gem 'activerecord',     :path => 'rails/activerecord'
gem 'activesupport',    :path => 'rails/activesupport'
```

However, again, I'd really like to know the most acceptable or standard approach to pulling in things you may need into Rails or any project for that matter where you really want to run with a release, but you've gotta have a patch here and now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this into your Gemfile

`gem rails, :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails.git", :branch => "master"`

And run `bundle update rails` when you need to pull latest changes. It is quite common pattern and you can use it for any gem.

Comment: Well, I do already understand that, however what do you do when you're trying to pull in a branch that's not yet made it into, for example, Rails proper?

For example, after a little more digging, I did indeed discover the patch I needed has not made it upstream yet.  I'm thinking that it might be wise to keep my own repos and just merge upstream...

Comment: You can fork rails to your own repo on github and manage it yourself, so you can update it from master when you want and merge patches earlier than they will be put into master.

Answer (score 0):

The only real acceptable answer so far that I've found is forking my own repo (either locally or on GitHub as that's what I'm using) and then cherry pick the changes I want on into my repo.  For example, in this case, I forked Rails proper and then cherry picked the appropriate patches on into that fork.  Then I can pull the Rails proper upstream changes in whenever desired.

This could also be done locally as noted, but in my case, I'm pushing to heroku and need to be able to pull my repo in from a server rather than my laptop as I don't have it set up to serve out the git repo.

So the real key for me was this answer here on StackOverflow: [Using GIT, how can I selectively pull / merge changes from another's 'fork'?](http://bit.ly/pyGpjD)