# Using forked (and patched) Rails 2-3-stable from git woes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bundler, ruby-on-rails-2

Everything started when we needed to apply this patch - http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2012/q2/504 to our app. The seemingly simple task turned up to be a pain in the *ss.

I knew I had the following options:

```
1.Monkeypatch;
2.Vendor rails;
3.fork Rails, apply the patch for 2.3 to the 2-3-stable 
branch and use it in the Gemfile.
```

Option #3 looked the most attractive to me, because it would allow me to rebase with the official repo, if needed; apply additional changes in a clean way - no need to clob the app repository with dozens of source files from Rails' gems (like vendoring would do). Monkey patching might have done the job, since the 2.3-stable branch is not being updated that often, but I don't really like opening classes for patches like this.

So I proceeded with #3.

```
1. I forked Rails;
2. I cloned my Rails repo locally;
3. I applied the 2.3 patch (http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2012/q2/att-504/2-3-sql-injection.patch)
using git am --signoff;
4. I pushed the changes.
5. I went to our app's Gemfile and added:

gem "rails","2.3.14", :git => "git://github.com/fullofcaffeine/rails.git", :branch => "2-3-stable"

6. Ran bundle install
```

Everything looked great, as bundle install finished successfully. When I tried to start the Rails server, I've got a **"no such file to load --initializer"** error.

After a bit of googling, I found the following post - [How to use a branch in a fork of rails in a project with bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043089/how-to-use-a-branch-in-a-fork-of-rails-in-a-project-with-bundler). I did exactly as he said, creating the gemspecs manually, and changed the Gemfile accordingly. When I tried to run bundler, surprisingly enough it ran without issues, and I saw this in the output:

```
Using activerecord (2.3.14) from git://github.com/fullofcaffeine/rails.git (at 2-3-stable)   Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: activerecord
  Version: 2.3.14
  File: activerecord-2.3.14.gem


Using rails (2.3.14) from git://github.com/fullofcaffeine/rails.git (at 2-3-stable)   Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: rails
  Version: 2.3.14
  File: rails-2.3.14.gem

...
```

and so on, for each of the gems I created a gemspec for.

However, when I try to run the Rails server, I get this:

```
$ script/server
/Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:572:in `load_spec_files': git://github.com/fullofcaffeine/rails.git (at 2-3-stable) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
    from /Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:385:in `local_specs'
    from /Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:555:in `specs'
    from /Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:356:in `converge_locked_specs'
    from /Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:345:in `converge_locked_specs'
    from /Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:143:in `resolve'
    from /Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
    from /Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:135:in `specs_for'
    from /Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:124:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
    from /Users/fullofcaffeine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357@myapp/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
    from ./script/../config/../config/preinitializer.rb:16
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:28:in `preinitialize'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:125
    from script/server:3:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

Also, if I try to find the gems that Bundler built (the message I pasted above about Bundler building the gems), I can't find them.

I'm really not sure what to do, such a simple task turned into a nightmare. I might just monkeypatch the classes if this find out I'm spending too much time on this.

- So the question really is - What is the most pragmatic solution for this *"I need to patch or customize Rails to my needs"* scenario?

**EDIT:** I solved the issue by monkeypatching for now, see my last comment below.

Comment: It tells you to run `bundle install`, did you do so again once you got that error instead of the first?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I did, and I followed the Bundler FAQ -- cleaned up everything I could (deleted Gemfile.lock, etc). Running bundle install --verbose and I get the same output - Bundler says it created the gems for each of the gems in the Rails repo, but then I get the same error when trying to start Rails.

Comment: Perhaps try upgrading Bundler? Your version is a bit behind the latest.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I just did. Bundler is now 1.1.4, but the problem persists. I just want to be able to cleanly apply that patch, and I think the best way, given the current issues with the git approach, is to just monkey patch. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: So, I solved the patch issue by MonekyPatching ActiveRecord::Base. I reverted the changes to the Gemfile, I'm using Rails 2.3.14 from Rubygems.org now and not from my git fork, and I created an initializer in config/initializers, and pasted the following code: http://pastie.org/4087875. Now, the application is using the fixed method from the patch (http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2012/q2/att-504/2-3-sql-injection.patch). However, I'd still like to know why the fork approach did not work, so if someone could shed some light, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved the patch issue by MonekyPatching ActiveRecord::Base. I reverted the changes to the Gemfile, I'm using Rails 2.3.14 from Rubygems.org now and not from my git fork, and I created an initializer in config/initializers, and pasted the following code: pastie.org/4087875. Now, the application is using the fixed method from the patch (seclists.org/oss-sec/2012/q2/att-504/2-3-sql-injection.patch). However, I'd still like to know why the fork approach did not work, so if someone could shed some light, I'd be grateful.