# How to use edge rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The title says it all. There are [really old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972113/how-do-i-install-edge-rails) that ask the same thing, but I think rails has moved on since then.

In my Gemfile, I've tried:

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
```

But that gives me `6.1.0.rc1 be11d1b` once I run `bundle install`. Current version of rails as of this writing is 6.1.3. Also tried `bundle update rails` after using the above line in the Gemfile. So it seems that a version older than current is being used when I try to pull from GitHub...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I wound up doing:

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
```

The `branch` part has to be there to make it do what I wanted. I tracked it down with
`rails new --help`, which led me to the `--edge` and `--master` options. Starting a new app with `rails new app_name --master` actually got me where I wanted to go.